# Do holes in pot lids make water boil faster?

Tags: physics, water

The responses to [this reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/30n9x0/what_will_you_argue_to_the_death/cpu8olt) make me think that it is a popular belief that holes in pot lids make water boil faster. The claim is that by lowering pressure, the water boils at a lower temperature.

I had always assumed they were there solely for convenience and safety - steam buildup can be a hazard - and that releasing steam would make it take *longer* to boil. I also don't see the pressure getting high enough to matter, but I don't know how the physics works out.

Is there truth to this claim? Might holes in pot lids make water boil faster?

Comment: Even if it's true (which I doubt), it's not *useful*: the cooking effect of boiling water comes from the temperature, not the fact that it's boiling.

Comment: The reason for the hole is so that the steam has a ready escape route rather than having to lift the lid clear by sheer pressure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't think a comment, with barely any votes, on Reddit, really counts as "notable". This question is unlikely to get a good answer, based on empirical evidence.

Comment: @oddthinking Theoretically all you'd need to test this one is a good cooking pot with a lid, a stove, a stopwatch and a drill -- but I'll let someone else handle the science. :)

Comment: This is probably a better fit for physics than Skeptics.The claim is technically true but the physics guys are probably better suited to explaining why and how it matters.